# ReCaptcha 2.0 The Remote Server Returned an ERror (Bad Request)

Tags: .net, recaptcha

I have the following Recaptcha call in my app

```
var result = false;

        var apiUrl = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiUrl);
        request.Method = "POST";


        string postString = string.Format("secret={0}&response={1}&remoteIp=127.0.0.1", ReCaptcha_Secret, res);
        const string contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postString);
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
        request.ContentType = contentType;
        request.ContentLength = postString.Length;
        StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
        requestWriter.Write(postString);
        requestWriter.Close();


        try
        {
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    JObject jResponse = JObject.Parse(stream.ReadToEnd());
                    var isSuccess = jResponse.Value<bool>("success");
                    result = (isSuccess) ? true : false;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
```

The secret and the response are correct, but no matter what I do I always receive the message:

> {"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."}

It is from My dev environment and I have 127.0.0.1 registered with captcha

am I missing something here? Ive spent a day trying to get this to work, on a job that I allocated 2 hours work for.

Any suggestions?

**Edit**

res is the response code generated by the Captcha challange to the user
According to the docs I need this and the secret_key to get my response

Comment: I tried to start a chat with You, but You didn't join. At first I thought it was JAVA. Wanted to help you with your problem, but only got raged by some people about my answer, so I quit. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks anyway, tried to join the chat, but you had obviously left

Comment: any more details in the error message?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: although the status in the exception when I debug is 'ProtocolError'